# Hibernate where in sub query

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a table like:

```
Users (user_id, name, age, country_id)
```

Now I want a query like:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
where country_id in (1,2,3,4,5)
```

There are no relationships for the user, I just want to do this without any associations.

I want to do this with Criteria query.

I see restrictions, but not sure if it has a where in clause:

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(User.class)
  .add(Restrictions.eq("country_id", countryId)
  .list();
```

So my change is that I have a list of country ids (List countryIds) that I need to pass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want 'country_id in (...)'?

If yes, then:

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(User.class)
 .add(Restrictions.in("countryId", countryIds)
 .list();
```

Also I used "countryId" - as in criteria you use property names, not table column names.

Comment: when you use the property, you remove the get prefix right? like getCountryId you use the private var?

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Integer> countryIds=//get data from either a query or criteria

Criteria c = // obtain criteria from session

Disjunction disJunction = Restrctions.disjunction();
disJunction .add(Restrictions.in("country_id", countryIds));
c.add(disJunction);
```

Answer (score 0):

Eugene's solution is the one to go with. You use Restrictions.in if you want to match multiple possible country ids.

You could also use Property.forName(...).in(...), like:

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(User.class)
    .add(Property.forName("countryId").in(countryIds))
    .list();
```